# Android Wear shows gradients?

Tags: android, gradient, wear-os

I'm trying to show a gradient like the next code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:centerY="50%"
        android:startColor="#ffdc241f"
        android:endColor="#FF000000"
        android:gradientRadius="100"/>
</shape>
```

But for some reason I only see this:

[image: Android Wear Screenshot]

What is the problem? Android Wear support gradients?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Android Wear does support gradients. I've tested your example as the background of a Button and it's working fine. Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: In a imageview, inside a linearlayout of the rounded and squared layout, but It only shows a solid red.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin Please maybe show us the code where (and how) exactly you're trying to use this drawable.